# cannot update rosdep

Tags: rosdep, ros-groovy, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi , when i try to init rosdep using `sudo rosdep init` , i have the error : `ERROR: cannot download default sources list from: https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list Website may be down.` 
I am using ros groovy on 12.04 ubuntu. Can anyone help me to troubleshoot? Many thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162996/cannot-update-rosdep/) by [manaXmizery](https://answers.ros.org/users/9931/manaxmizery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It means exactly what it says: it tried to open a connection to github.com to download the default sources.list, and failed.

I would start troubleshooting by confirming that your machine has internet connectivity and can ping github.com. You can also try visiting that url directly or trying to fetch it with `curl` or `wget`.

If you're only have problems connecting to github, you can always check their [status page](https://status.github.com/) to see if their servers are having problems.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5